# Navbar is appearing on homepage but not on post page (newbie here)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I'm a total newbie, please do bear with me.

I'm following a course online where the instructor shows navbar  appearing on homepage root path but also on other pages like the posts page. I followed exactly his instructions, but for some reason the navbar which is a partial, is only appearing on the homepage but NOT on the posts page - the code for navbar is as follow and the code for the other pages are all on https://github.com/cheese1884/-mywebsite

Thanks, guys.

```
<div class='container'>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <%= link_to "LessonRoll", root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor03" aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Posts', posts_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>

        </li>
          <% if current_user %>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class = "nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="download">Admin Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="download">
                <%= link_to "App Settings", app_setting_path(@app_setting), class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              Link
              </div>
            </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>



        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <% if !current_user %>
           <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
            </li>
             <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
            </li>
            <% else %>
           <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="download"><%= current_user.username if current_user %> <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="download">
                <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
              </div>
            </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry i'm trying to get navbar to display on post page as well. I made a typo - typed 'now' instead of 'not'

Comment: I found that once i deleted the code layout 'yeti' from posts_controller, the navbar apppears again on post page. Don't know why but for now my issue is resolved. Anyone can clarify the reason why this resolved the issue ? Thanks, guys

Comment: Do you have a layout `yeti` defined?

Comment: i do as per github link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your yeti.html.erb, you need to put the navbar outside the `yield` section:

```
<body>
  <%= render partial: 'navbar' %> <!-- or code for navbar -->
  <div>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

#### **Edit** : multiple layouts explaination

> Rails uses a simple convention to find the correct layout for your
>   request. If you have a controller called `ProductsController`, Rails
>   will see whether there is a layout for that controller at
>   `layouts/products.html.erb`. If it can't find a layout specific to your controller, it'll use the default layout at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.
>   ([source](https://learn.co/lessons/rails-layouts-and-templates))

In your case you can add a custom layout such as `yeti.html.erb` and specify your `PostsController` to use this layout with `layout 'yeti'`

**Why the navbar is appearing on homepage but not on post page (original question)**

Because as i answered above, you need to add the navbar partial inside the `yeti.html.erb` layout same as you did in the `application.html.erb` layout.

**Why the navbar design is different**

Because in application layout you link the `application.scss` stylesheet which only imports bootstrap ([here](https://github.com/cheese1884/-mywebsite/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss#L1))

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

In the yeti layout, you link `yeti/theme_manifest.scss` as stylesheet which imports both "bootstrap" and the overriding "theme" ([here](https://github.com/cheese1884/-mywebsite/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/yeti/theme_manifest.scss#L2))

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'yeti/theme_manifest', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

I hope this will help you to see more clearly.

Comment: Hey sovalina, i took your suggestion, inserted render partial for navbar outside yield, but also keeping layout 'yeti' in posts_controller - problem persisted. Once i removed layout 'yeti' from posts_controller (and keeping the navbar outside yield), the navbar appeared immediately on posts page. Do you know why this resolved the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the navbar partial in your "yeti" layout too ? (it does not exit in [the code you linked](https://github.com/cheese1884/-mywebsite/blob/master/app/views/layouts/yeti.html.erb#L11))

Comment: it worked. but the navbar styling in posts https://ibb.co/jY0u88 is now different from how the navbar styling is in the homepage https://ibb.co/g0Rj88

Comment: just to add to my 1st reply to your answer - The thing is, the navbar appears as 'yeti' in posts page though having removed layout 'yeti' code from posts_controller

Comment: @Mark it's not possible. i cloned your project just to be sure and if i comment `layout 'yeti'` in posts_controller, the navbar toggle to the "classic" bootstrap style... and it makes sense: *"If Rails can't find a layout specific to your controller, it'll use the default layout at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`"* ([source](https://learn.co/lessons/rails-layouts-and-templates)). You can check your logs to see which template is rendered when you get posts#index for example.

Comment: Yea thats what I did as in commenting the line out.  Sorry to keep harping but I was just wondering as the instructor doesn't comment that line layout yeti out but gets the same layout as the homepage? I'd definitely check the server log again when I get back to my desktop.

Comment: added layout 'yeti' based on your latest answer to posts_controller. Removed @import "theme" from theme_manifest (as that's the overriding theme as you mentioned). And now the layout is exactly the same in posts page and homepage. Hope I understood you correctly. Please correct me if I'm wrong, sovalina. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Sovalina - is there a place where I can reach you online? I'm searching for a mentor to start building 1 of my apps. Thanks.